# Emacs 25.1: linum-update-window: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil

Tags: debugging, emacs

I have upgraded emacs to 25.1 and faced linum related error:
Message buffer says linum-update-window: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil

Any idea?

Comment: Run `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and try again. You will see where it blows up.

Comment: What @YuriSteinschreiber said. And if what to do is not clear then, please post the backtrace here, as part of your question. IOW, please provide more info about the error.